# Java. Need a program with a simple https client-server interaction with encryption

Tags: java, eclipse, https, certificate, client-server

I used this example of server and client class:

[server](http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/SSL-Socket-Server-Example-SslReverseEchoer.html)

[client](http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/SSL-Socket-Client-Example-SslSocketClient.html)

Then I used the following commands:

```
keytool -genkey -alias my_a -keystore server.jks
keytool -export -keystore herong.jks -alias my_a -file my_a.crt
keytool -import -keystore public.jks -alias my_home -file my_a.crt
```

Then I don't know what to do. I use Eclipse and I don't know how to work with certificates in it.

P.S. Or maybe someone can give me a better solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the JVM about any key and truststores.  Do a search on the properties javax.net.ssl.trustStore, javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword, javax.net.ssl.keyStore, javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword